# Stack-based buffer overrun attempting to create an object of class

Tags: c++, buffer-overrun

Prehistory: I am creating template class(HashMap< KeyType, ValueType >), which should implement abstraction of map using hash tables. To solve collisions in hash tables method of chains is used. I get error when I attempt to initialize HashMap object in *main.cpp* using constructor *HashMap()*.

> Error: "stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based
>   buffer overrun."

So, the code:

Part of private section(only all member variables and method *createBuckets()*, which is used in constructor *HashMap()*)

```
private:

/* Constant definitions */

   static const int INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT = 101;
   static const int MAX_LOAD_PERCENTAGE = 70;

/* Type definition for cells in the bucket chain */

   struct Cell {
      KeyType key;
      ValueType value;
      Cell *next;
   };

/* Instance variables */

   vector<Cell *> buckets;
   int nBuckets;
   int numEntries;

/* Private methods */

/*
 * Private method: createBuckets
 * Usage: createBuckets(nBuckets);
 * -------------------------------
 * Sets up the vector of buckets to have nBuckets entries, each NULL.  If
 * asked to make empty vector, makes one bucket just to simplify handling
 * elsewhere.
 */

void createBuckets(int new_nBuckets) {
    if (new_nBuckets == 0) nBuckets = 1;
    buckets = vector<Cell *>(new_nBuckets, NULL);
    this->nBuckets = new_nBuckets;
    numEntries = 0; 
}
```

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>::HashMap() {
    createBuckets(INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT);
}
```

The most strange that the error happens rarely and when it does not happen, class works successufully. If I recompile the programm, there is no error and it do not happen until the next recompling. If it can matter, I use Visual Studia 2017 for writing this programm.

I suppose that problem is caused by creating of vector in method *createBuckets*, but I can not see any problem with this.

Comment: *The most strange that the error happens rarely and when it does not happen, class works successufully.* -- Meaning your program is *not* working correctly.  Second, why do you need the `nBuckets` variable when the `vector<Cell*>` knows the number of buckets already?  Third, C++ doesn't work this way, where the site of the crash is the reason for the issue.   The program could have been corrupted before that function is called.

Comment: *Second, why do you need the nBuckets variable when the* `vector<Cell*>` *knows the number of buckets already?* -- I suppose, you meant that we can find number of buckets using method size() for vector, but I consider use of variable nBuckets as better way cause it increases readability of code. May be I am not right.


*Third, C++ doesn't work this way, where the site of the crash is the reason for the issue. The program could have been corrupted before that function is called.* -- I did only initialization in main.cpp and the same error happend.

Comment: *but I consider use of variable nBuckets as better way cause it increases readability of code.* -- No, the code is not more readable.  Every programmer knows what `vector::size()` returns and is always correct.  We don't know what `nBuckets` will return, or even if it is updated correctly.  All extra variables do is increase the chance of a bug occurring.  If anything, add a function `getNumBuckets` or something like that, that returns `vector<Cell*>::size()`.